# Uploading R Shiny app that reads external CSV data file

Tags: r, shiny

I have created an `R Shiny` app.  It seems to run fine on my computer.  I now need to upload it so others can use it.  I created an account at: https://www.shinyapps.io/ and use the following two lines within the default `R GUI`:

```
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/simple_RShiny_files/surplus10')
```

I get the following `warning` where `line 4` reads the external `CSV` file in the `subfolder data` which is followed by an `error` below.  The `app.R` file is in the folder `surplus10`:

```
The following potential problems were identified in the project files:

-----
app.R
-----
The following lines contain absolute paths:
4: policy.data <- read.csv('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/simple_RShiny_files/surplus10/data/policy.outputs_June6_2020.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Paths should be to files within the project directory.
Do you want to proceed with deployment? [Y/n]: Y

Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 2430142...--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
DONE
Deploying bundle: 3246501 for application: 2430142 ...
Waiting for task: 744319366
  building: Building image: 3633169
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages

An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).

Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/mark_/Documents/simple_RShiny_files/surplus10/data/policy.outputs_June6_2020.csv': No such file or directory
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : cannot open the connection
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I imagine that once the `app` is uploaded the `path` to the data file is no longer valid.  If that is the case which `path` should I use to read the `CSV` file?  Which path do I use in the `deployApp` statement?  I have never attempted to upload an `app` before and do not know what a `project directory` is.  Sorry for my beginner's confusion.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed line 4 in the `app.R` file that reads the external `CSV` data file to:

```
policy.data <- read.csv('data/policy.outputs_June6_2020.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

the app uploaded without `error`.

I did not change my original `path` in the `deployApp` statement:

```
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/simple_RShiny_files/surplus10')
```